# Price not showing in marketplace after minted from smart contract

Tags: web3js, ether, nft, opensea

We have created a fronted which require client to fill in name,description,price and attach an image. After mint, name, description and image able to display in `Opensea` created, but price not showing.

[image]

It seems like we have to edit the NFT by clicking the "Sell" button to fill in the price. Is it possible to show the price just below the name once it is minted from the smart contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about displaying the price on Opensea then **no**.

Opensea has its own buy/sell process, where you have to first approve the marketplace and then place the NFT on sale. Since Opensea stores the sales off-chain, so you will have to go through the sale process on Opensea in order for it to show the price.

Comment: thanks..how about others markertplace?

Comment: There is no standard that would enable you to set prices on contract level. So no you will have to put the itrm on sale on each matketplace separately.